# GPAC MP4Box fullrange flag

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, encoding, mp4box

A few years ago I was trying to encode some GoPro videos with Handbrake to reduce their file size and store them.

After a few attempts, I noticed that the colors on the encoded videos were looking a bit faded

- Note: I am not talking about compression quality issues.

After research, I understood what was the issue. GoPro was falsely flagging the video color range as 'fullrange', when in reality it wasn't, creating problems after encoding.

Looking through some forums and searching some more I utilized a script that uses MP4Box to recreate a video file with the full range flag set to off. Then encoding of said file produced an excellent result.

I currently have a newer, GoPro hero 8 camera and use h264 + HEVC options for video file encoding.

My script now fails with the following error:

> ```
> Unrecognized import option fullrange=off, ignoring
> [FileIn] Failed to open C:\***Filepath***\GX011821.MP4:fullrange=off
> [Importer] Cannot load filter for input file >"C:\***MyFilepath***\GX011821.MP4:fullrange=off"
> Error importing C:\***MyFilepath***\GX011821.MP4:fullrange=off: Requested URL is not valid or cannot be found
> ```

The command that used to work boiled down to this:

```
echo
    
mp4boxmod -add filename.mp4:fullrange=off newFilename.mp4

pause
```

Has full range been deprecated/substituted with something else?
Please advise with any other possible options

Answer (score 1):

GPAC contributor here: could you report that on our [github issues](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues) please?

Please don't forget to mention your full command-line and GPAC version. We won't be able to help you without these information.

And of course don't forget to mention your issue back here in case it can help other users :)

Answer (score 1):

So I've raised the issue and it turns out the version I have been using with the fullrange option was a fork of gpac.
These changes were backported in the master though now. You can read more here
https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues/1636